# Present MFMailComposeViewController from modal FormSheet on iPad?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Has anyone been successful showing the standard Apple `MFMailComposeViewController` from a `UIModalPresentationStyleFormSheet` view controller on the iPad?

When I do this the view shows as expected but when the user taps any of the input text views, the subject for example, and the keyboard slides pressing the Cancel button will show the "Delete Draft" & "Save Draft" popover outside of the screen bounds.

If I change the modal view to full screen it works properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you are presenting it as a Form Sheet then.  Using this code works wonders for me:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setSubject:@"Subject"];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
mailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: You're right this does work, thanks. The only issue I see here with this is if you have the popover visible (showing Cancel, etc.) and then rotate the iPad, the popover is displaced off the screen as before. Any thoughts on that? Thanks!

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue by presenting the modal view controller with style `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`.

Comment: It was UIModalPresentationCurrentContext that fixed it for me as well.